# How to change the category url jusy show /category/%category_id% in wordpress?

Tags: customization, categories, urls

I want to change the article url as

```
www.***.com/post/%post_id%
```

For example,

```
www.***.com/post/156/
```

And now, I did it.

But I don't know how to change the category like this. For example,

```
www.***.com/category/12/
```

Generally, the category url is:

```
www.***.com/category/cat1/cat1.1/cat1.1.1/
```

I want to get:

```
www.***.com/category/cat1.1.1/
```

And now I want to only display the ID of the cat1.1.1, like:

```
www.***.com/category/12/ ( the id of cat1.1.1 is 12 )
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean in the last part about the subcategory? Can you give an example?

Comment: For example, generally, the category url is www.***.com/category/cat1/cat1.1/cat1.1.1/, and now, I want to get this, www.***.com/category/cat1.1.1/. This is my meaning. And now I want to only display the ID of the cat1.1.1, like www.***.com/category/12/ ( the id of cat1.1.1 is 12 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my answer on the internet.

```
function numeric_category_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $custom_rules = array();
    foreach ( $rules as $regex => $rewrite ) {
        $regex = str_replace( '/(.+?)/', '/([0-9]{1,})/', $regex );
        $rewrite = str_replace( '?category_name=', '?cat=', $rewrite );
        $custom_rules[ $regex ] = $rewrite;
    }
    return $custom_rules;
}
add_filter( 'category_rewrite_rules', 'numeric_category_rewrite_rules' );

function numeric_category_link( $category_link, $term_id ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) {
        $permastruct = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct( 'category' );
        $permastruct = str_replace( '%category%', $term_id, $permastruct );
        $category_link = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $permastruct, 'category' ) );
    }
    return $category_link;
}
add_filter( 'category_link', 'numeric_category_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to Admin panel -> Settings -> Permalinks. Change your permalink structure to numerical. Also change your category base to *category* . This will give you the permalink structure you're asking for, I.E:

> www.***.com/category/12/

I'm not sure what you mean by

> and just show the last subcategory.

Comment: For example, generally, the category url is www.***.com/category/cat1/cat1.1/cat1.1.1/, and now, I want to get this, www.***.com/category/cat1.1.1/. This is my meaning. And now I want to only display the ID of the cat1.1.1, like www.***.com/category/12/ ( the id of cat1.1.1 is 12 )

Comment: Did you try doing as it says in my answer? If you choose numeric permalink stucture you will not have that hierarchical structure you're referring to. Please try it and mark my answer as solved if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it's not what I want